# Calculate minimum value not between set of ranges

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry, intervals

Given an array of circles (x,y,r values), I want to place a new point, such that it has a fixed/known Y-coordinate (shown as the horizontal line), and is as close as possible to the center BUT not within any of the existing circles. In the example images, the point in red would be the result.

Circles have a known radius and Y-axis attribute, so easy to calculate the points where they intersect the horizontal line at the known Y value. Efficiency is important, I don't want to have to try a bunch of X coords and test them all against each item in the circles array. Is there a way to work out this optimal X coordinate mathematically? Any help greatly appreciated. By the way, I'm writing it in javascript using the Raphael.js library (because its the only one that supports IE8) - but this is more of a logic problem so the language doesn't really matter.
[image]

Comment: In the left figure, why would the red dot not be at one of the two points of intersection of the fourth circle (counting from the left)? It seems to my eye that those points are closer to the center of the right circle than the indicated point is to any circle center. Or does "the center" mean something else? If so, what?

Comment: sorry - by center I mean the vertical line in the diagram (for simplicity treat that as X=0)

Comment: What do you mean by "try a bunch of X coords"? You'll only have to try the intersection points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the equation of a circle is *(x - c<sub>x</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y - c<sub>y</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = r<sup>2</sup>*. Therefore you can easily find the intersection points between the circle and  X axis by substituting *y* with *0*. After that you just have a simple [quadratic equation](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/quadform.htm) to solve: *x<sup>2</sup> - 2c<sub>x</sub>x + c<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup> + c<sub>y</sub><sup>2</sup> - r<sup>2</sup> = 0* . For it you have 3 possible outcomes:

- No  intersection - the determinant will be irrational number (NaN in JavaScript), ignore this result;
- One intersection - both solutions match, use *[value, value]*;
- Two intersections - both solutions are different, use *[value1, value2]*.

Sort the newly calculated intersection intervals, than try merge them where it is possible. However take in mind that in every program language there approximation, therefore you need to define delta value for your dot approximation and take it into consideration when merging the intervals.

When the intervals are merged you can generate your *x* coordinates by subtracting/adding the same delta value to the beginning/end of every interval. And lastly from all points, the one closest to zero is your answer.

Here is an example with *O(n log n)* complexity that is oriented rather towards readability. I've used *1*10<sup>-10</sup>* for delta :

```
var circles = [
    {x:0, y:0, r:1},
    {x:2.5, y:0, r:1},
    {x:-1, y:0.5, r:1},
    {x:2, y:-0.5, r:1},
    {x:-2, y:0, r:1},
    {x:10, y:10, r:1}
];

console.log(getClosestPoint(circles, 1e-10));



function getClosestPoint(circles, delta)
{
    var intervals = [],
        len = circles.length, 
        i, result;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        result = getXIntersection(circles[i])
        if (result)
        {
            intervals.push(result);
        }
    }

    intervals = intervals.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.from - b.from;
    });
    if (intervals.length <= 0) return 0;
    intervals = mergeIntervals(intervals, delta);

    var points = getClosestPoints(intervals, delta);
    points = points.sort(function(a, b){
        return Math.abs(a) - Math.abs(b);
    });
    return points[0];
}

function getXIntersection(circle)
{
    var d = Math.sqrt(circle.r * circle.r - circle.y * circle.y);
    return isNaN(d) ? null : {from: circle.x - d, to: circle.x + d};
}

function mergeIntervals(intervals, delta)
{
    var curr = intervals[0],
        result = [],
        len = intervals.length, i;
    for (i = 1 ; i < len ; i++)
    {
        if (intervals[i].from <= curr.to + delta)
        {
            curr.to = Math.max(curr.to, intervals[i].to);
        } else {
            result.push(curr);
            curr = intervals[i];
        }
    }
    result.push(curr);
    return result;
}

function getClosestPoints(intervals, delta)
{
    var result = [], 
        len = intervals.length, i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
    {
        result.push( intervals[i].from - delta );
        result.push( intervals[i].to + delta );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is roughly the same approach I proposed, but it is not _O(n)_ complexity. After generating the intervals, you sort them before merging, which is an _O(n log n)_ operation. Also, it's not clear that using `delta` pessimistically (to, in effect, widen the intervals) is well-advised. The computational errors are equally likely to be positive or negative, so an argument can easily be made that the intervals should be narrowed by `delta` rather than widened. Probabilistically, it's better to simply use the average `delta` value, which is zero.

Comment: Thank you for your pointer, I completely missed the sorting in the complexity evaluation, it is updated now. I might communicate the `delta` role wrong, it is used to put the point outside of the circle area, because if you take the interval edge you will be at the point where the circle intersects the axis and as far as I understand that does not satisfy the condition.

Comment: Overall, this is a nice solution (complete with code, which, I have no doubt, earned you a well-deserved check mark). Regarding `delta`, OP wants a point that is "not within" any circle. I interpret that to mean not in the _interior_ of any circle, which would allow points on the circumference. You also use `delta` to expand the intervals when testing whether to merge, which strikes me as unjustifiable. I'd simply eliminate it because it adds complexity and has (at best) dubious theoretical foundation.

Comment: Yes if the points on the circumference are allowed I agree that `delta` needs to be removed. However if not, there is one extremely rare, but possible scenario where the difference between two intervals can be exactly `delta` (or less if the `delta` is not the smallest possible unit the system can distinct) which will give us false solution.

Comment: Well, I submit that using `delta` poses an equal (if not greater) risk of giving a false solution (where the distance between two intervals is both mathematically and computationally positive but computationally less than delta). In that case, using `delta` will cause intervals to be merged that should have (and would have) remained distinct.

Answer (score 2):

I'd approach your problem as follows:

1. Initialize a set of intervals *S*, sorted by the X coordinate of the interval, to the empty set
2. For each circle *c*, calculate the interval of intersection *I<sub>c</sub>* of *c* with with the X axis. If *c* does not intersect, go on to the next circle. Otherwise, test whether *I<sub>c</sub>* overlaps with any interval(s) in *S* (this is quick because *S* is sorted); if so, remove all intersecting intervals from *S*, collapse *I<sub>c</sub>* and all removed intervals into a new interval *I'<sub>c</sub>* and add *I'<sub>c</sub>* to *S*. If there are no intersections, add *I<sub>c</sub>* to *S*.
3. Check whether any interval in *S* includes the center (again, fast because *S* is sorted). If so, select the interval endpoint closest to the center; if not, select the center as the closest point.

Comment: +1 for collapsing the intervals, that seems to be what the OP didn't think of. Btw, you could check whether any interval includes the center during calculating all the intersections, even before sorting them.

Comment: @Bergi - Excellent point about tracking as you go which interval (if any) contains the center. Because of the merging, there can be at most one such interval.

Comment: thanks Ted, this looks promising & will try in JS tomorrow. Forgive my ignorance but when you refer to 'a set of intervals', do you mean an array of Xstart and Xend values (ie, a range along the x axis)? By 'collapse Ic...'   do you mean, for example, if one is 1 < x < 5 and another is 4 < x < 10, collapsing this into a single 1 < x < 10 interval?

Comment: @Dave - Yes, each interval should be a representation of a continuous range along the x axis. Regarding collapsing, what you describe is exactly what I meant. Another term might be "merging" the intervals.

Answer (score 0):

1. create the intersect_segments array (normalizing at x=0 y=0)
2. sort intersectsegments by upperlimit and remove those with upperlimit<0
3. initialize point1 = 0 and segment = 0
4. loop while point1 is inside intersectsegment[segment]

   4.1. increment point1 by uppper limit of intersectsegment[segment]

   4.2. increment segment
5. sort intersectsegments by lowerlimit and remove those with loerlimit>0
6. initialize point2 = 0 and segment = 0
7. loop while point2 is inside intersectsegments[segment]

   7.1. decrement point2 by lower limit of segment

   7.2. decrement segment
8. the point is minimum absolute value of p1 and p2

Comment: I don't think it's valid in step 2 to remove intersection segments that have an upper limit < 0. They may overlap with segments that contain the center and the closest point may be the left edge of one of those segments. (I haven't analyzed the rest of your algorithm for correctness, but this jumped out at me right away.)